# How can I use the same ExtJS model proxy with modifications in different ViewModels?

Tags: extjs

I'm using ExtJS 5 and I'm trying to figure out a way to use a proxy defined in a model in several different ViewModels, adding different extraParams to any specific ViewModel.  Here is pared-down code to try to illustrate what I'm trying to do (please forgive any minor errors that don't relate to the question- this is not my actual code).  Basically, I have a proxy in the model with some paramsToPath that all ViewModels will want.  In a specific ViewModel I want to add some extra params (optional, that may not be added in other ViewModels).  This is NOT working- I was hoping that I could use a proxy defined in a model (or store) with modifications added in the ViewModel.  I've tried adding some extraParams in the ViewModel with the hope that those extraParams would merge to the proxy defined in the model, but it is not working.  Any ideas of how I can accomplish this?

Here is the model:

```
Ext.define('EmployeeManager.model.Employee', {
extend : 'EmployeeManager.model.Base',

idProperty : 'id',
fields : [ {
  name : 'id',
  type : 'string'
}, {
  name : 'name',
  reference : 'string'
} ],

proxy : {
  paramsToPaths : [ {
    params : [ 'locationId' ],
    path : '/location/{0}'
  } ]
 }
});
```

Here is the store:

```
Ext.define('EmployeeManager.store.Employees', {
  extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
  alias : 'store.employees',
  requires : [ 'EmployeeManager.model.Employee' ],

  model : 'EmployeeManager.model.Employee'
});
```

Here is the ViewModel:

```
Ext.define('DpcManager.view.dpc.copy.EmployeeModel', {
  extend : 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
  alias : 'viewmodel.employee',

  data : {
    locationId: null,
    employeeName: null
  },

  stores : {
    employeeStore : {
        type : 'employees',
        remoteFilter : true
         proxy: {
             type : 'rest',
             url : '../employee-services/employee/',
             extraParams: {
                 fields: 'id,personId',
                 locationId: '{locationId}',
                 name: '{employeeName}'
             }
         }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: did you try to override the the buildUrl function in the proxy?

Comment: No, I haven't tried this.  Is there a way to add POST parameters that are not in the URL?  In this case "locationId" is a query parameter so I could build the URL to include that, but "name" is just a request parameter.

Comment: just for a clarification, do you try to add query parameters or change the path?